# Android login e senha "cache"

Tags: android

Olá, como fazer um login automático?

ex: fiz um aplicativo para android com login, senha e webservice, quando o usuário loga eu mando as informações e retorno true ou false. Como faço para armazenar no telefone o usuário e senha informado para os próximos acessos não pedir a mesma ?

Comment: Kebler, minha sugestão é usar `SharedPreferences`. Ele já tem uma segurança padrão, mas você pode até encriptar caso necessário. Mas o ideal é guardar um `token` e não uma senha. Dê uma olhada nas perguntas da tag: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharedpreferences

Comment: Estou justamente nessa parte do meu projeto, eu estou criando um token, por enquanto junto as informações de login e criptografo, e salvo usando sharedpreferences. No meu caso estou fazendo comunicação SSL/TLS via socket , e cada vez que a comunicação inicia eu envio o token para o servidor poder reconhecer o cliente.

Comment: Se sua comunicação for via http, acho que a cada requisição você deve enviar o token ou então trabalhar com cookies pode ajudar, mas não sei se seria seguro.

Comment: para sua maior segurança deixe o **SharedPreference** privado, [Activity.MODE_PRIVATE]

Answer (score 5):

Você pode user `SharedPreferences` para salvar as informações, assim na segundo vez que o usuário acessar seu aplicativo você verifica se esses informações estão preenchidas e faz o login automático.

Exemplo para salvar as informações usando `SharedPreferences`:

```
public static final String NOME_PREFERENCE = "INFORMACOES_LOGIN_AUTOMATICO";
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(NOME_PREFERENCE, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

 editor.putString("login", "usuario01");
 editor.putString("senha", "1234");
 editor.commit();
```

E para você recuperar estas informações salvas:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String login= prefs.getString("login", null);
String senha= prefs.getString("senha", null);
if (login!= null) {
   // existe configuração salvar
} else {
  // não existe configuração salvar
}
```